# SQL Query using where clause in Prepared Statement

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, database

I am working on a gate entry system, in which i am inserting in-time and out-time. While writing sql query for out-time, it is showing error at WHERE clause. I am not able to solve the error. What will be exact SQL query?

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Timestamp sqlTime = new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime());
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into ENTRY(OUTTIME) values(?,?,?,?) WHERE (ENTRY.ROLLNUMBER='"+rollno+"' AND ENTRY.OUTTIME ='NULL')");
ps.setTimestamp(4,sqlTime);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Why would an insert have a where statement? Shouldn't it be an update statement?

Comment: there is no such syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `UPDATE` the existing row

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE ENTRY SET OUTTIME =? WHERE ROLLNUMBER=?");
ps.setTimestamp(1,sqlTime);
ps.setString(2, rollno);
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't how an `insert` statement works. If you want to update an existing record, you'd need an `update` statement:

```
PreparedStatement ps = 
    con.prepareStatement("UPDATE entry SET outtime = ? WHERE rollbumber = ?");
ps.setTimestamp(1, sqlTime);
ps.setInt(2, myRollNo);
```

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense for an insert statement to have a `WHERE` clause which refers back to the same record.  I propose the following code:

```
java.sql.Timestamp sqlTime = new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime());
String sql = "INSERT INTO ENTRY(OUTTIME) VALUES (?)";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setTimestamp(1, sqlTime);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

Either you update or change your insert statement as below:

```
"insert into ENTRY(OUTTIME) select col1 from ENTRY WHERE ENTRY.ROLLNUMBER='"+rollno+"' AND ENTRY.OUTTIME ='NULL'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Timestamp sqlTime = new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime());
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("update ENTRY set OUTTIME= ?  WHERE ENTRY.ROLLNUMBER='"+rollno+"' AND ENTRY.OUTTIME is NULL");
ps.setTimestamp(4,sqlTime);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: This answer is prone to SQL injection.